# res.revalidate() is not a function in NextResponse of Nextjs for on-demand ISR

Tags: typescript, next.js

NextResponse does not have  `res.revalidate('/')`. i'm using `v12.2.5` but it is there from `v12.2.0`. i want to use on-demand ISR in typescript.

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2#on-demand-incremental-static-regeneration-stable

```js
export default async function handler(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
    try {

        await res.revalidate('/');
        return res.json({ revalidated: true });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any luck with a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `NextRequest` and `NextResponse` we must use `NextApiRequest` and `NextApiResponse`.

```js
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {

        await res.revalidate('/');
        return res.json({ revalidated: true });

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating');
    }
}
```